# Can the class method name be defined in the struts-config.xml file in Struts1?

Tags: java, struts-1

Is there a way to define which method name is executed in an Action class (Action, BaseAction, DispatchAction, etc) in the `struts-config.xml` configuration file in Struts1?

I know that by default, the `DispatchAction.execute()` method will parse the parameter list for a "method" parameter and execute that method, however I was hoping to see if there was a way to define the method in the configuration file as I can do in Struts2.

Is the Struts1 framework able to support this out of the box?

Answer (score 2):

You can extend `org.apache.struts.action.Action` in your new controller and call any execute method you want from the overridden `execute()` method and then each new action you add will extends your new controller.

Another way that I never tried is to modify in `struts-tiles.tld` of your project configuration in the following element to specify your own controller:

```
<attribute>
     <name>controllerClass</name>
     <required>false</required>
     <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
     <description>
     <![CDATA[
     <p>Class type of a controller called immediately before page is inserted.</p>
     <p>Controller is used to prepare data to be render by inserted Tile.</p>
     <p>See also controlerUrl</p>
     <p>Class must implements or extends one of the following :</p>
     <ul>
       <li>org.apache.struts.tiles.Controller</li>
       <li>org.apache.struts.tiles.ControllerSupport</li>
       <li>org.apache.struts.action.Action (wrapper org.apache.struts.action.ActionController is used)</li>
     </ul>
     <p>See also controllerUrl. Only one of controllerUrl or controllerClass should be used.</p>
     ]]>
     </description>
  </attribute>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry it is too late in the evening. The following is exactly what you described above. Just define the parameter param for a DispatchActionMapping in struts config. Call it 'method' or 'action' or whatever. The assigned/passed value in URL must match the exact name of the method in your DispatchAction. Method signature with the four params. Return Type ActionForward. There is no other way. I believe you already know this approach. That's the most 'out of the box' case.

Comment: My goal is to not use the url parameter. I want to specify the action method in the config file, not in the url. In struts2, I can specify the method name in the config file. I guess there is no way in struts1?

Comment: No way to do that in struts-config in struts1!